# Adding a user object to a manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I'm writing a simple game using Django. My Game model has a many-ti-many field `players`:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='playing_games', blank=True,
                                     null=True, default=None)
```

My current code to add a player to a game:

```
    def add_player(self, player)
        if not player in self.players.all():
            self.players.add(player)
```

causes the following `ValueError`:

```
Cannot add "<User: xyz>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Added:**

At this point, the `player` is a `User` object referring to the current user, and the game object has **not** been saved yet.

This function is called from `Game.__init__` after the call to super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)

Basically, what I'm trying to do it to make sure that the current `user` is one of the `players` in the newly created `game`.

Comment: please try to do checking with `not self.players.filter(id=player.id).exists()` instead of `not player in self.players.all()`. it's super performance killer!

Comment: Are objects saved before calling `add_player` function? could you provide more informantion about how you call  `add_player` ?

Comment: objects are not saved yet at that point. This is done in init